# Truststore Mulesoft - Unable to find valid certification path

Tags: ssl, mulesoft, truststore

I am trying to call SFMC Cloud endpoint and I need to connect through TLS. I created a trust store that contains 2 certificate one for smfc token authentication and another for the actual soap endpoint. I check the truststore and both certificates are already imported. However when I tried to deploy my application, it throws this error :

```
org.mule.soap.api.transport.DispatcherException: An error occured while sending the SOAP request 
  at com.mulesoft.connector.salesforce.marketing.internal.connection.provider.SalesforceMarketingTransportDispatcher.dispatch (SaleforceMarketingTransportDispatcher.java:58) ~[mule-sfdc-marketing-cloud-connector-3.1.6-mule-pluigin.jar:?]
  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoker(ClientImpl.java:530) ~[cxf-core-3.3.5]
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoker(ClientImpl.java:441) ~[cxf-core-3.3.5]
  at org.mule.soap.internal.client.AbstractSoapCxfClient.invoke(AbstractSoapCxfClient.java:116) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.3.2.jar:?]
  at org.mule.soap.internal.client.AbstractSoapCxfClient.consume(AbstractSoapCxfClient.java:102) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.3.2.jar:?]
  at com.mulesoft.connector.salesforce.marketing.internal.connection.SalesforceMarketingCloudConnection.execute(SalesforceMarketingCloudConnection.java:62) ~[mule-sfdc-marketing-cloud-connector-3.1.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
  at com.mulesoft.connector.salesforce.marketing.internal.connection.SalesforceMarketingCloudConnection.execute(SalesforceMarketingCloudConnection.java:56) ~[mule-sfdc-marketing-cloud-connector-3.1.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
  at com.mulesoft.connector.salesforce.marketing.internal.connection.SalesforceMarketingCloudConnection.validate(SalesforceMarketingCloudConnection.java:50) ~[mule-sfdc-marketing-cloud-connector-3.1.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
  at com.mulesoft.connectors.commons.template.connection.provider.ConnectorConnectionProvider.validate(ConnectorConnectionProvider.java:36) ~[mule-connector-commons-2.1.0.jar:?]
  at com.mulesoft.connectors.commons.template.connection.provider.ConnectorConnectionProvider.validate(ConnectorConnectionProvider.java:16) ~[mule-connector-commons-2.1.0.jar:?]
  at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.connectivity.oauth.ExtensionOAuthUtils.validateOAuthConnection(ExtensionOAuthUtils.java:188) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20201013:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.connectivity.oauth.BaseOAuthConnectionProviderWrapper.validate(BaseOAuthConnectionProviderWrapper.java:42) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20201013:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.doTestConnectivity(DefaultConnectionManager.java:186) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.lambda$testConnectivity$1(DefaultConnectionManager.java:169) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.doTestConnectivity(DefaultConnectionManager.java:176) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.testConnectivity(DefaultConnectionManager.java:152) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter$EagerConnectionManagerAdapter.testConnectivity(DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.java:176) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.testConnectivity(DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.java:98) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.CompositeConnectionManager.testConnectivity(CompositeConnectionManager.java:115) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.module..extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance$1.doWork(LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.java:194) [mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.api.retry.policy.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execure(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:52) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rety.async.RetryWorker.run(RetryWorker.java:56) [mule-core-4.3.0-20201013.jar:4.3.0-20201013]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTasl.java:264) [?:?]
  at org.mule.service..scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111) [mule-service-scheduler-1.3.2/:?]
  at org.mule.service..scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54) [mule-service-scheduler-1.3.2/:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:641) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage360) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshaker.java:392) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedActyion.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedActyion.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061) ~[?:?]
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:689) ~[?:?]
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:274) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:723) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLFilter.java:345) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:637) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:349) ~[?:?]
  at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.SwitchingSSLFilter.handleRead(SwitchingSSLFilter.java:74) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExcecutorResolver$9.executer(ExcecutorResolver.java:119) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.ProcessExecutor.executer(ProcessExecutor.java:77) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:540) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:103) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348) ~[?:?]
  at org.glashfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279) ~[?:?]
... 7 more
```

I verified that the certificates are in the truststore using this command :

```
   keytool -list -v -keystore truststore.jks
```

Here is the configuration for the salesforce marketing cloud :

```
   <sfdc-marketing-cloud:config name="Salesforce_Marketing_Cloud_Config" doc:name="Salesforce Marketing Cloud Config" doc:id="ceb6487e-d6ac-4aee-b7b3-d292d9657b3d" >
        <sfdc-marketing-cloud:oauth-client-credentials-connection serviceUrl="${api.sfmc.url}" >
            <tls:context >
                <tls:trust-store path="keystore.jks" password="test123" type="jks" />
            </tls:context>
            <sfdc-marketing-cloud:oauth-client-credentials clientId="${api.sfmc.client.id}" clientSecret="${api.sfmc.client.secret}" tokenUrl="${api.sfmc.token.url}" />
        </sfdc-marketing-cloud:oauth-client-credentials-connection>
    </sfdc-marketing-cloud:config>
```

I'm using this app runtime :

```
   <properties>
        <app.runtime>4.3.0-20201013</app.runtime>
        <munit.version>2.3.1</munit.version>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.4.2</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
```

SFMC connector version :

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-sfdc-marketing-cloud-connector</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4</version>
      <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
   </dependency>



Did I missed something? Thanks!
```

Comment: How are you using this keystore in a Mule application? With which connector?  Please share the XML of the configurations and flows as text. What version of Mule Runtime and the connector you are using? Also add the complete error message, including all lines above and below the error shown, which are only of part of the exception stack trace.

Comment: Updated the contents with additional details.

Comment: I don't see anything amiss. Next step for troubleshooting could be to enable Java SSL debug log in ssl level and see if it provides insight on why it is not finding the certificate. See https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-enable-SSL-debug-logging-in-MuleSoft-Products for instructions.